# How to create the new UIView in xcode under xib

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xib

I want to create a Timer Application in xcode apps.

But it needs two `UIView`s, I have only one `UIView`.

How to add the another `UIView` in xib?

Comment: Have you gone through any Apple documentation before making an app ??

Comment: Welcome to SO and to iOS development.  You will probably get more constructive answers if you describe your need in a little more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search before u ask [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166663/how-to-add-new-xib-files)

You can use storyboard it is better read about it [link](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html)

Answer (score 1):

To create a standalone user interface (XIB):

File -> New File -> iOS -> User Interface

Then choose:

Application (includes delegate and window)
Window
View
Empty
To create a new UIViewController class with a user interface:

File -> New File -> iOS -> Cocoa Touch -> UIViewController subclass -> Click Next

Then, name the new view controller class and select "With XIB for user interface."

**OR**

Choose objective-c class and then select `UIViewController` as subclass.

Apple moved all objective-c class templates into the "Objective-C class" template. They have custom functionality, like "With xib for user interface", there too.

Comment: i know but UIViewController  not display

Comment: You want to create a new file or simply an xib ??

Comment: This would create all the 3 files check all your files... But tell me have u followed all the instructions though ??

Comment: when i click new file it just display the obejective c class, category , protocaol and rest case

Comment: Have you tried my edited post ?? I think it will work .. check it out

Comment: it k guy, leave it, i have another idea. when i click the add button get the information in small popup window its possible?

Comment: Yes it is quite possible ... u would hav to use a popupcontroller or u can work with a uiview also .. tell me your exact issue :)

Comment: i am new in this xcode . so do u have sample code for popup meas send it me, or give the links

Comment: You can create an alertview if you like .... Here are some links please refer ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988564/how-to-implement-a-pop-up-dialog-box-in-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737911/how-to-display-temporary-popup-message-on-iphone-ipad-ios

Comment: You are welcome @Muthukamatchi any further help please tell on my gmail id ... Check the answer if its correct :)

Comment: Then you can simple call a uiview on a button click and add anything in it at runtime like entering in a textfield etc.... add the uiview from the xib .... Basically wat do u want on runtime ?

Comment: Please continue chat on gmail with me as stack overflow does not allow long chats within comments :) ... Ill explain to u on my gmail id here - tejesh.gill@gmail.com ... connect the button through xib set the delegates :)